# Balance of an address depending on a time variable

Tags: solidity, contract-development, timestamp

is there a way to compare the balance of an address at two different times or in general check the balance of an address at a specific time?

I would like to do something like...

```
uint256 public startTime
address public exampleAddress

function exampleFunction () public constant returns (uint value) {
    if (balanceOf(exampleAddress) < balanceOf_atStartTime(exampleAddress)) {
        returns X;
    }
}
```

My preferred input would be a variable like defined above, but an Unix Timestamp or an event would be suitable as well.

Does anyone know a way to do this kind of operation?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No you can't get an address's past balance through Solidity. But there is a solution using web3js.

Long answer: You could do something like this to get the balance of an address at a certain time as seen here:
[Get Balance History of address](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/40266/get-balance-history-of-address)

with the following code.

```
let blockNum = web3.eth.blockNumber;
const historicTimestamp = new Date(historicDate).getTime();
while(true) {
  const block = web3.eth.getBlock(blockNum);
  if(block.timestamp < historicTimestamp) break;
  --blockNum;
}

//The blockNumber here is your required block number
web3.eth.getBalance(address, blockNumber).then(balance => `Balance at block number is ${balance}`);
```

Then you could pass it to your smart contract and compare the two balances there or compare in web3 completely.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done from the smart contract itself.

The best bet you could have is to try using the [blocknumber parameter](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1287) from web3 and estimate the block number as close as possible to your desired timestamp.